# How to create folder per each line of a file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want create per each line of text file create nested directory.

```
for (( i=0;i<=$(cat filename | wc -l);i++ ))
do
mkdir /PATH/$i
done
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: above code. do not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping through the content of a file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash) because then it is just a matter replacing `echo` by `mkdir` (possibly with option `-p` ).

Comment: Counting how many lines there are if you don't actually care about the number is just an antipattern. The proper way to read a file is `while read -r line; do ... ; done <file`

Comment: iwant with for loop

Comment: Then you are confused. `for` makes sense when you already have the items you want to loop over in memory; but reading the file into memory so you can loop over its items is simply a waste of memory.

Comment: @tripleee I think this shouldn't be marked as a duplicated. OP does not care for the actual lines but only for the line numbers. The "duplicate" is misleading.

Comment: @tripleee Not really a duplicate of that, as OP doesn't seem to care *what* the lines are, just how many there are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the third part of `for (( init; condition; increment))`. The correct version should be

```
for (( i=0; i<=$(cat filename | wc -l); i++ )); do
    mkdir /PATH/$i
done
```

However, this is a very crude way to tackle the problem.
A better approach would be the following (courtesy of tripleee)

```
seq 0 $(wc -l <filename) | xargs -I mkdir /PATH/{}
```

Note that both commands will create one directory more than the file has lines. For a file with two lines the directories `0`, `1`, and `2` will be created. If this was an bug in your original script, change the `0` in the scripts to `1`.

Comment: And this creates a directory for each line number, so better written `seq 1 $(wc -l <filename) | xargs -I mkdir /PATH/{}`

Comment: @tripleee thank you for the input. This was exactly what I was working on right now.